# is there any way to get data from editable pdf using javascript and angular or any other javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angular, pdf-to-html

i am trying to display a PDF in UI that has some fields to be filled by the user and i am trying to access the filled data but i cannot access can anyone suggest a way to access the form data in PDF or any other easy method to implement this feature

i already tried using embed to display PDF but i cannot access the
 user filled data

final result is like user should be able to edit any number of times the fields in the PDF only once he can submit the data to database

Comment: You have code or we should assume it  . ?

Comment: i dont have code i had sample pdfs for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst trying to achieve the same thing, I ended up using [pdfmake.org](http://pdfmake.org) to render the pdf.

The user is editing the front-end website that looks like the pdf which updates the variables the rendered pdf references with every focus-out event.

Comment: i have pdf with many textboxes and radio buttons i want to user to fill the form. and i want that details to be saved to databases. i have different pdf with different fields so i am trying not to write html a for each pdf  and directly render and get the filled data to send to database

Comment: The thing is, editing the pdf directly in your browser will be hard imo. If you assume page size is always the same Letter/A4 you can style it with css for it to be fixed in size with min/max width/height. After that you can order your database user/document1/page1/field1 and so on and bundle requests and send them all together.

With pdfmake I think you'll be more flexible towards your design choices.

Comment: we have multiple pdf then we need to make multiple html pages to render dynamically is there any other to avoid writing html code

Comment: I really doubt it!